# Drag and Drop Image from UITableviewCell to other View

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, drag-and-drop

I am working on a iPhone app, where I need to drag an image from `UITableViewCell` 
and drop it in some other `UIView` outside the tableview.

(imageview added as :[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView]).

Please help me on this, any useful hint , sample code ?? Touch event delegates are not triggering since i am adding UIImageView to UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get much event in `UIImageView` so use `UIButton` and try something like this to drag:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouch:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vehicle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];

- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIControl *control = sender;
    control.center = point;
}
```

when your center point match to other `UIView` use `[UIView adSubview:]` method to add UIButton in `UIView`

I have take this code from [Basic Drag and Drop in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707858/basic-drag-and-drop-in-ios/4711054#4711054)

Have a look at : [Drag an Image within the Bounds of Superview](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/graphics/drag-an-image-within-the-bounds-of-superview.html)

Comment: to implement it with UIImageView this is a simple demo : http://mobiledevelopertips.com/graphics/drag-an-image-within-the-bounds-of-superview.html

Comment: Yes, it does helps to move the button but since button is inside UITableViewCell, so when dragging button outside tableview , button will be behind the other views/main view. The problem is we can not see the dragging movement of button outside the tableview (its hidden behind otherviews).

Comment: You have to change parent view every time UIButton cross bounder of its curent parent. Or you can do is when UIButton start drag move that to main parent UIView (self.view) and bring it to front.

Comment: I have Done [[button superview] bringSubviewToFront: button];  that  brings the button to top of UItableView , but can you provide me a line of code for bringing that button to the top of main view(window) because  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button]; is not working in mycase, button is still behind the main view.

Comment: If we going to add as  [self.view addsubview:imgbtn] , then the button will appear somewhere else in the view , then in its original position. For eg: button in cell has a origin say (0,0) , if we add that button to self.view then that button will appear on the top left of the screen!!

Comment: ye u have to change frame according to new view position. there are 4 method to do this : – convertPoint:toView:
– convertPoint:fromView:
– convertRect:toView:
– convertRect:fromView:

Comment: Go here and learn about this 4 method http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView: