# UISwipeGestureRecgoniser in more than up, down, left and right Swift

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

For my app I would like to have it so the user can swipe in every direction using the UISwipeGestureRecgoniser. Would it be possible to instead of having just up, down, left and right, but one for ever degree and therefore I can use that to move my sprite in that direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UISwipeGestureRecgonizer` doesn't have such possibility, it only contains 4 directions

If you want just to move object along with user finger you can try dragging event (`UIControlEventTouchDragInside`). 
Here is nice example how to achieve this: [Basic Drag and Drop in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707858/basic-drag-and-drop-in-ios)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :D